# what circumstances does javascript catch an empty error object?

Tags: javascript, web

in my web project, i try to catch all web error and send error to server;

my code like this:

```
window.onerror = (message, url, lineNo, columnNo, errorObj) => {
    var originErrorCloned = Object.getOwnPropertyNames((errorObj || {})).reduce(function(result, key){
       result[key] = error[key];
       return result;
    }, {});
    // do send originErrorCloned object to server;
    fetch('xxx', {body: JSON.stringify({error: originErrorCloned})})
};
```

in server, i get some error look like empty object

```
{}
```

normal error be like

```
{
   "error": "{\"stack\":\"xxx\\n xxx \\n xxx \\n",\"message\":\"Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined\"}"
}
```

in my previous version code, i try report error like this

```
window.onerror = (message, url, lineNo, columnNo, errorObj) => {
    fetch('xxx', {body: JSON.stringify({
       message: errorObj.message,
       stack: errorObj.stack,
       name: errorObj.name
    })});

};
```

if errorObj's properties not all undefine, the server will get report like {"message":"", stack:"",name: ""} ,but server get report like "{}",
so i guess errorObj's properties(message,stack,name) are all undefine(void 0),because JSON.stringify will ignore undefine properties name and keep null(eg: empty string) properties name

**so my question is how to create a javascript Empty Error ?**

and i found most part of empty error object report from applewebkit(safari) or gecko(firefox) webengine and device is Windows PC;

i try to use safrai devtools to create a Error like

```
new Error('');  // get {message: '', ...others}
new Error(void 0); // get {stack: 'xxxx', ...others}
new Error({});  // get {message: '[Object Object]'}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames((errorObj || {}))`?

Comment: I see you edited your question, but my point is: are you sure you're not assigning an empty object to `originErrorCloned`? Did you try to log the error itself before cloning it?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, this fault is  i forgot to modify code copied to stackoverflow, my project has no errro like ths

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, I make sure that originErrorCloned has a value when a normal error is thrown, and I don't know how to send the native Error object to the server, so I convert the native Error object into a normal Object and stringify it

Comment: My question is simple: do a `console.log(errorObj)` inside the function. Is it ever empty?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado , I can't reproduce this problem on my own machine, ``console.log(errorObject)`` just get normal erro stack like this ``Error: xxx\n    at <anonymous>:1:1``

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, yes ,the ``errorObj`` maybe is empty , so the question is what circumstances does javascript catch an empty error object, or how can i report this special Error Object to server

Comment: @GerardoFurtado my english is not very good, tanks for comment, back to the question , I mean, why the caught error will not have error.name or error.message or error.stack

Comment: no worries, I'm not an English speaker myself. Again, I'll try to be very clear: forget about `originErrorCloned`, just focus on the error you get. Is it ever empty? No. Thus, you will have all properties you're looking for. Sorry, I can't help you more than this, I hope someone else can give you an appropriate answer.